# Blank page when report footer is unsuppressed

Tags: crystal-reports

My subreport consists of nothing but a dynamic picture, using the given field to find the correct images to display. I placed this subreport in the footer of the my main report, which works fine as long as subreport can find the images.

When there is no image to be displayed, (`isnull({field})`) a blank page is created at the end of the report. How can I disable this blank page? I've tried the following but nothing has worked:

Main report:

- Suppress Blank Subreport
- Suppress Blank Section (in report footer)
- Check and uncheck Keep Together (in report footer)
- Formula `PageNumber = TotalPageCout` (in report footer)

Subreport:

- Suppress OLE Object using formula
- Suppress detail section where OLE object is located at using formula

Answer (score 0):

Try suppressing all other sections, other than the Details section inside the subreport.

After doing so, activate Suppress Blank Subreport and Suppress Blank Section in the Report Footer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes all sections of the sub-report (except the part with the OLE object) are suppressed. Blank subreport and blank section (footer) are also suppressed.

Comment: So how looks your suppress formula inside subreport detail section? Are you sure that the balnk page at the end is caused by report footer section?

Comment: Do you have New Page Before on the Report Footer or New Page After on Group Footer/ Details section on main report?